# Extract all the matched groups of a regular expression in a string

Tags: regex, ocaml

Is there a way to extract in one call all the matched subgroups of a string according to a regular expression.

I have a date like this:

`Thu, 07 Apr 2022 15:03:32 GMT`

And I created the following regexp to extract all the parts of this date:

```ml
let re =
    Str.regexp
      {|\([a-zA-Z]+\), \([0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z]+\) \([0-9]+\) \([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\).*|}
```

And to extract each parts I use it like this:

```ml
let parse_date date =
  let re =
    Str.regexp
      {|\([a-zA-Z]+\), \([0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z]+\) \([0-9]+\) \([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\).*|}
  in
  let wday = Str.replace_first re {|\1|} date in
  let day = Str.replace_first re {|\2|} date in
  let mon = Str.replace_first re {|\3|} date in
  let year = Str.replace_first re {|\4|} date in
  let hour = Str.replace_first re {|\5|} date in
  let min = Str.replace_first re {|\6|} date in
  let sec = Str.replace_first re {|\7|} date in
  Format.eprintf "RE DATE: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s@." wday day mon year hour min
    sec
```

If the parts were stored in an array I could easily use it like this:

```ml
let parse_date date =
  let re =
    Str.regexp
      {|\([a-zA-Z]+\), \([0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z]+\) \([0-9]+\) \([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\).*|}
  in
  let parts = Str.match_groups re date in (* this function doesn't exist *)
  let wday = parts.(1) in
  let day = parts.(2) in
  let mon = parts.(3) in
  let year = parts.(4) in
  let hour = parts.(5) in
  let min = parts.(6) in
  let sec = parts.(7) in
  Format.eprintf "RE DATE: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s@." wday day mon year hour min
    sec
```

but this doesn't appear to exist. Is there another way to do it or is my solution the only one available?

Since this isn't a XY problem, my goal is really to extract each part of a date so maybe there's another solution than using Str and I'll be happy to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Str.matched_group` to return a particular capture group's match:

```ml
let parse_date date =
  let re = Str.regexp
      {|\([a-zA-Z]+\), \([0-9]+\) \([a-zA-Z]+\) \([0-9]+\) \([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\):\([0-9]+\).*|} in
  if Str.string_match re date 0 then
    let wday = Str.matched_group 1 date in
    let day = Str.matched_group 2 date in
    let mon = Str.matched_group 3 date in
    let year = Str.matched_group 4 date in
    let hour = Str.matched_group 5 date in
    let min = Str.matched_group 6 date in
    let sec = Str.matched_group 7 date in
    Format.sprintf "RE DATE: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s@." wday day mon year hour min sec
  else
    "RE DATE: Not matched"

let _ = parse_date "Thu, 07 Apr 2022 15:03:32 GMT" |> print_endline
```

The `Str` package is pretty primitive, though. I'd suggest using a different library for regular expressions, like [PCRE-Ocaml](https://mmottl.github.io/pcre-ocaml/). It does have a way to get an array of matched groups:

```ml
let parse_date2 date =
  let rex = Pcre.regexp
      {|([a-zA-Z]+), ([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*|} in
  try
    let parts = Pcre.exec ~rex date |> Pcre.get_substrings in
    let wday = parts.(1) in
    let day = parts.(2) in
    let mon = parts.(3) in
    let year = parts.(4) in
    let hour = parts.(5) in
    let min = parts.(6) in
    let sec = parts.(7) in
    Format.sprintf "RE DATE: %s %s %s %s %s %s %s@." wday day mon year hour min sec
  with Not_found -> "RE DATE: Not matched"

let _ = parse_date2 "Thu, 07 Apr 2022 15:03:32 GMT" |> print_endline
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple format with fixed number of fields and separators, Scanf might be enough:

```
let date s = Scanf.sscanf s "%s@, %02d %s %d %d:%d:%d %s" 
  (fun day_name day month year h m s timezone ->
    day_name,day,month,year,h,m,s,timezone
  )

let x = date "Thu, 07 Apr 2022 15:03:32 GMT"
```

Comment: Sadly I can't accept two answers. I chose the other one because I never liked Scanf, I find it really slow but in my case it would apply perfectly