# How to exclude only negative numbers in parentheses from a string with Regex

Tags: regex, ocaml

I'm working in OCaml and I'm trying to find a regex that can match all the positive numbers in a string while excluding the negative ones between parentheses. My currently failing regex is:

```
^[1-9]+[0-9]*
```

and my sample is:

```
(-5) -> ignored : GOOD
5 -> matched : GOOD
(-19) -> ignored : GOOD
19 -> matched : GOOD
300free -> only 300 is matched : GOOD
5 + 8 -> only 5 is matched : BAD
(-1) + 5 -> 5 is not matched : BAD
5 + (-1) -> 5 is matched and (-1) is ignored: GOOD
1 (-1) -> 1 is matched and (-1) is ignored : GOOD
(-2) 1 -> 1 is not matched : BAD
```

My regex to match the negative ones, including the parentheses, is:

```
[(][-][0-9]+[)]
```

and it works properly. What should I change in the first regex to fix the BAD ones?

Comment: Try `\b(?<!\(-(?=\d+\)))[1-9]\d*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't allow me to use this regex. I should have specified that it's a regex for OCaml. I'll edit the question properly.

Comment: What is a "regex for OCaml"? There are several different implementations. I guess you mean the one used by `Str`?

Comment: Also, most regex implementations are similar enough that you'll be able to translate between them.

Comment: @glennsl Yes, using Str.string_match However it seems like \b(?<![(-])[0-9]*[0-9] is working properly. I'm testing to verify it.

Comment: You can use PCRE regex engine,  as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71784656/3832970), with my top comment regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the parts that you don't want out of the way, and use a capture group for the values that you want to keep.

```
\(\s*-\d+\s*\)|\b([1-9]\d*)
```

- `\(\s*-\d+\s*\)` Match `-` and 1+ digits between parenthesis
- `|` Or
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match as the beginning
- `([1-9]\d*)` Capture **group 1**, match a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits 0-9

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EsiTJf/1).

---

If you also want to allow matching 0, you can use

```
\(\s*-\d+\s*\)|\b(\d+)
```